# Delay loading grid in processmaker

Tags: grid, paging, processmaker, form-load

I've got a Process Maker BPM 3.2 
I Got Project that have 300 row in grid(With Pictures).
but form loading had delay 
Does anyone have any  idea who can i fix it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow At this site you are expected to try to write the code yourself. After doing more research, if you have a problem you can post **what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. I suggest reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question and the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/6676466).

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase your max execution time and also your max_input_vars in the php.ini, then restart your httpd.

If you are loading a grid with 300 data with all text, there might be a tendency that it will not show all but if with picture, that will be eating up resources and loading time.

I hope this helps